# Convert Javascript HMAC to C#

Tags: c#, hmac

```
hmac = CryptoJS.algo.HMAC.create(CryptoJS.algo.SHA256, secret_buffer);
    hmac.update(path, secret_buffer);
    var Sign= hmac.finalize();
    var signature = base64_encode(Sign);
```

Already Tried with C# as like but unable to get the same answer

```
var key1 = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test"));
        var key2 = key1.Concat(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("Test"));
        var key3 = sha1.ComputeHash(key2);
        var hmac=  Convert.ToBase64String(key3);
```

Please give some solution ?

Comment: Can you provide input and expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JS code is equivalent to the following code (assuming that your `base64_encode()` method is implemented correctly):

```
var secret_buffer = "secret";
var path = "text";  

signature = CryptoJS.HmacSHA256(path, secret_buffer).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Base64);
console.log(signature);
```

In С#, the equivalent would be:

```
string secret_buffer = "secret";
string path = "text";       

using (var hmacsha256 = new HMACSHA256(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(secret_buffer)))
{
    var hash = hmacsha256.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(path));
    var signature = Convert.ToBase64String(hash);

    Console.WriteLine(signature);
}
```